# Delete white spaces in textbox when copy pasted with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a textbox of order id(7 digits), which in normal cases you copy paste from email to the textbox, many times you accidently copy one or two white spaces which causing annoying validation error.

I want jquery code in my `Layout\MasterPage` that does't allow writing white spaces and when copy paste **(with keyboard or mouse)** numbers with white spaces removes the spaces and keeps the numbers only.

The above should happen only on textboxes with class `white-space-is-dead`

Comment: What's wrong with `$('.white-space-is-dead').change(function() {this.trim()});`?  Do you need to trim space between words too?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey,doesn't work, see the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3CRg/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do

```
$('.white-space-is-dead').change(function() {   
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,""));
});
```

Updated copy of your [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/U3CRg/23/)

Note that `\s` may be [more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) than you like.  If so, use a literal white space instead

`.replace(/ /g,""));`

Comment: @gdoron, that's for testing...sorry I meant to take that out. I updated the answer.

Comment: it's better to pass a callback function to the val method in that case, like so: `$( this ).val(function( index, oldValue ) {
 return oldValue.replace( /\s/g, "" );
});` it avoid 2 calls to `$(this)` and `.val()`

Comment: It writes out to the error console in firefox.  You can see it with FireBug.  Its an easy way to see variable values when you are debugging.  Its usage is simple `console.log(variableName)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.white-space-is-dead').change(function() {   
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g,""));
});
```

This will remove all the white spaces using a regular expression.

Comment: this will replace all white space in the string, including all space characters, ne lines, tabs, etc.

Comment: Can you please be kind and make jsFiddle? I did't succeeded to make it work. see my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3CRg/22/

Comment: I updated the code in my comment... (hope this is good enough) :)