# HTML - onpaste event remove extra spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input text field with extra spaces,

```
12 12 12
```

and I would like to remove the extra spaces after pasted it into my text field.

```
121212
```

However, my code doesn't seem to work for me.

**HTML**

`<input type="text" id="text1" onPaste="try123(this.id);"/>​`

**JavaScript**

```js
function try123(fId) {
cleanExtraSpace = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var pastedText = '';
        //IE browser OnPaste Event Handler
        if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { 
        pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
      } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
        pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      }
        //Remove start and end extra spaces on paste
        this.value = pastedText.replace(/\D/g, '');
    };
fId.onpaste =  cleanExtraSpace;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" onPaste="try123(this.id);"/>​
```

I was referring to this post, 
[JavaScript - Remove Space on paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943924/javascript-removing-spaces-on-paste)

Can someone help me to rectify it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

Input: `<input type="text" id="nums" name="nums">`

```
var input = document.getElementById('nums');

function handleInput(e) {
  var el = this;

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    el.value = el.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }, 0);
}

input.addEventListener('paste', handleInput, false);
```

Here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/lozobamequ/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you. but is it possible to call the function from the HTML? example like `<input type="text" id="nums" name="nums" onpaste="handleInput(this.id)">` because I have a lot of text field requires to apply this function.

Comment: Inline JavaScript is pretty much a bad practice and outdated now days. You will be better off doing something like this:  http://jsbin.com/verojugebe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: +1 This worked for me also. I'm curious though (and have tried finding the answer)--why do you have to wrap the `el.value.replace` function in a `window.setTimeout`? I tried simplifying it to just `this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');`, but obviously that didn't work or you would have written it that way. Why is the `setTimeout` needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try This One.

HTML

`<input type="text" id="search" name="search">`

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);

function handlePaste(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    var pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    var searchField = document.getElementById('search');
    searchField.value = pastedData.trim();
}
```

Using this you can remove extra spaces (keyboard paste as well as mouse paste).

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: This solution does not take into account cursor position or selected text - it does instead replace the entire value with the data from the clipboard. Therefore I wouldn't recommend using this piece of code.